# How to capture start time and end time of certain duration in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am building an app where I want to capture when did a lecture starts and ends.

I am aware of Date type but I just want to capture time. I am using ReactiveForms.

Comment: Hi, KapilPadwekar while asking a question always form your question as per standards and always provide some code of what you have tried by that it easier for the user to understand your question and also to answer.

Comment: Hello Nikhil Gangurde, Sorry for not making my question clear. And I really feel that I should have tried out by myself before posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

It was really very simple. Changes are as follow:

In HTML page:

```
<input class="form-control" type="time" formControlName="startTime">
```

In component file:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    startTime: []
})
```